# end daemon processes with multiprocessing module

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, multiprocessing

I include an example usage of multiprocessing below. This is a process pool model. It is not as simple as it might be, but is relatively close in structure to the code I'm actually using. It also uses sqlalchemy, sorry.

My question is - I currently have a situation where I have a relatively long running Python script which is executing a number of functions which each look like the code below, so the parent process is the same in all cases. In other words, multiple pools are created by one python script. (I don't have to do it this way, I suppose, but the alternative is to use something like os.system and subprocess.) The problem is that these processes hang around and hold on to memory. The docs say these daemon processes are supposed to stick around till the parent process exits, but what about if the parent process then goes on to generate another pool or processes and doesn't exit immediately.

Calling terminate() works, but this doesn't seem terribly polite. Is there a good way to ask the processes to terminate nicely? I.e. clean up after yourself and go away now, I need to start up the next pool?

I also tried calling join() on the processes. According to the documentation this means wait for the processes to terminate. What if they don't plan to terminate? What actually happens is that the process hangs.

Thanks in advance.

Regards, Faheem.

```
import multiprocessing, time

class Worker(multiprocessing.Process):
    """Process executing tasks from a given tasks queue"""
    def __init__(self, queue, num):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.num = num
        self.queue = queue
        self.daemon = True

    def run(self):
        import traceback
        while True:
            func, args, kargs = self.queue.get()
            try:
                print "trying %s with args %s"%(func.__name__, args)
                func(*args, **kargs)
            except:
                traceback.print_exc()
            self.queue.task_done()

class ProcessPool:
    """Pool of threads consuming tasks from a queue"""
    def __init__(self, num_threads):
        self.queue = multiprocessing.JoinableQueue()
        self.workerlist = []
        self.num = num_threads
        for i in range(num_threads):
            self.workerlist.append(Worker(self.queue, i))

    def add_task(self, func, *args, **kargs):
        """Add a task to the queue"""
        self.queue.put((func, args, kargs))

    def start(self):
        for w in self.workerlist:
            w.start()

    def wait_completion(self):
        """Wait for completion of all the tasks in the queue"""
        self.queue.join()
        for worker in self.workerlist:
            print worker.__dict__
            #worker.terminate()        <--- terminate used here  
            worker.join()              <--- join used here

start = time.time()

from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import *

dbuser = ''
password = ''
dbname = ''
dbstring = "postgres://%s:%s@localhost:5432/%s"%(dbuser, password, dbname)
db = create_engine(dbstring, echo=True)
m = MetaData(db)

def make_foo(i):
    t1 = Table('foo%s'%i, m, Column('a', Integer, primary_key=True))

conn = db.connect()
for i in range(10):
    conn.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS foo%s"%i)
conn.close()

for i in range(10):
    make_foo(i)

m.create_all()

def do(i, dbstring):
    dbstring = "postgres://%s:%s@localhost:5432/%s"%(dbuser, password, dbname)
    db = create_engine(dbstring, echo=True)
    Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker())
    Session.configure(bind=db)
    Session.execute("ALTER TABLE foo%s SET ( autovacuum_enabled = false );"%i)
    Session.execute("ALTER TABLE foo%s SET ( autovacuum_enabled = true );"%i)
    Session.commit()

pool = ProcessPool(5)
for i in range(10):
    pool.add_task(do, i, dbstring)
pool.start()
pool.wait_completion()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing) already has classes for worker pools, right?

The standard way is to send your threads a quit signal:

```
queue.put(("QUIT", None, None))
```

Then check for it:

```
if func == "QUIT":
    return
```

Comment: Hi Thomas. Thanks for the helpful reply. Yes, I *was* thinking of using multiprocess.Pool. Maybe that would be better than a home-made solution. Please comment if you think that is the case. Hmm, map_async looks like the ticket. I can do  pool.map_async(do, range(10), callback=results.append). Though I'd like to be able to pass more than one argument. Thanks also for the queue.put suggestion. I was looking at signals and pipes,which I guess is unnecessarily complicated. Interesting blog, btw. Regards, Faheem.

Comment: You're welcome. In general, I'd always go for a ready made solution unless there's some reason it doesn't do what you want. You can only ever pass one argument with any sort of `map` function, but there are ways round it.

Comment: Well, the simplest thing to do is to wrap all the arguments into one                                     argument, eg. using a dictionary. I'm unclear about the advantages between apply_async and map_async, but I figure one result object is better than many, so I guess I'll use map_async. Thanks.

Comment: @Faheem: That's one way, another is to use `zip()` to join them together. Or if only one argument is changing, you could get the other ones to the function separately (although that might be trickier using a straightforward pool).

Answer (score 3):

My way of dealing with this was:

```
import multiprocessing

for prc in multiprocessing.active_children():
    prc.terminate()
```

I like this more so I don't have to pollute the worker function with some if clause.