# CUDA-accelerated code run from a Jupyter Notebook through Pybind11 leaves zombie processes which cannot be killed

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, cuda, pybind11

This is many layers of tools, but hoping somebody can point out where we went wrong.

I am working on creating a standard set of Jupyter notebooks for running the [oxDNA](https://github.com/lorenzo-rovigatti/oxDNA) model, which implements coarse-grained molecular dynamics simulations.  The core simulation code is C++/CUDA with a Pybind11 interface called `oxpy` which allows control of the simulations from Python, including Jupyter Notebooks.  When run from the Python interpreter, it seems to work fine, however there are certain conditions in which running the code from notebooks leaves a process running on the GPU visible with `nvidia-smi` which can only be ended with `kill -9`.

The conditions I have found are the following:

1. When the simulation is run by the main Python thread and exits successfully, the kernel is unlocked and able to run additional cells, including more simulations, however there is a zombie process left on the GPU.  Restarting the kernel does not get rid of the process on the GPU (despite killing it on the CPU), and running a second simulation with the restarted kernel creates a second zombie process.

```py
import oxpy
with oxpy.Context():
    manager = oxpy.OxpyManager('sim0/input')
    manager.run_complete()
```

2. When the simulation is run using `multiprocessing.Pool` and `Pool.terminate()` is called while the simulation is running, it leaves behind a zombie process.  This does not happen if the simulation is allowed to finish.  Note that interrupting a Jupyter kernel sends a `KeyboardInterrupt`, but you have to interrupt twice to get out of the loop in this case.

```py
import oxpy
import multiprocessing as mp

def launch(inp):
    print("running:", inp)
    with oxpy.Context():
        manager = oxpy.OxpyManager(inp)
        manager.run_complete()


pool = mp.Pool(1)

try:
    response = [pool.apply_async(launch, (i,)) for i in ['sim0/input']]
    for i, r in enumerate(response):
        try:
            r.get(100000000)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("Caught KeyboardInterrupt1, terminating workers")
            pool.terminate()
            break
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error in simulation", i)
            print("Error was:", e)
            continue
        
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Caught KeyboardInterrupt2, terminating workers")
    pool.terminate()
    pool.close()
    
pool.close()
```

I created a minimal example [here](https://github.com/ErikPoppleton/oxpy_minimal), which does require oxDNA to be installed with Python and CUDA enabled.  See the README.

I am guessing it has something to do with a missing command to free memory or reset the CUDA device, but neither I nor the owner of the code have been able to figure out what it is.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19322129/681865

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to kill zombie processes created by multiprocessing module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19322129/how-to-kill-zombie-processes-created-by-multiprocessing-module)